# Source not found while Remote Debugging spring based web app on tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, remote-debugging, jpda

I have a Spring-based web application running on Tomcat which I wish to debug in Eclipse. 
I managed to run Tomcat in debug mode (JPDA). But I am encountering a **Source not found** error.

I have seen similar questions asked before but I couldnt find an exact answer.

The stack trace where **Source not found** occurs is

```
Daemon Thread [http-8080-3] (Suspended) 
    Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 602 
    SpringTestService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2f23d34d.update(SpringTestVO) line: not available   
    SpringTestManager.update(SpringTestForm) line: 65   
    SpringTestAction.doExecute(ActionMapping, ActionForm) line: 65  
    SpringTestAction(BaseAction).execute(ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 196  
    DelegatingActionProxy.execute(ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 106 
    TilesRequestProcessor(RequestProcessor).processActionPerform(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Action, ActionForm, ActionMapping) line: 419  
    TilesRequestProcessor(RequestProcessor).process(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 224  
    ActionServlet.process(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 1196   
    ActionServlet.doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 432 
    ActionServlet(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 637   
    ActionServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 717   
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 290  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206  
    StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 233    
    StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 191    
    StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 127   
    ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 103    
    StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 109 
    CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) line: 293  
    Http11Processor.process(Socket) line: 861   
    Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Socket) line: 606    
    JIoEndpoint$Worker.run() line: 489  
    Thread.run() line: 662
```

The classes `SpringTestService`, `SpringTestManager`, `SpringTestAction`, `SpringTestForm` and `SpringTestVO` are written by me.

It is unable to find source for `Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor`, which is in the Spring library.

I have added the required libraries and JARs and projects in the "Source folder while creating Debug Configurations.

Comment: What are the class names?  Are you suggested to add source to the class displayed?

Comment: I have added the source files of the entire module, which contains all the classes that I need to debug.

Comment: Well, what are the class names for those classes you cannot step into?

Comment: I have class `SpringTestManager` that has a field of class type `SpringTestDAO`, which is autowired. Both these classes are written by me. I have put a breakpoint in `SpringTestManager`. I can't step into any of functions of `SpringTestDAO` called by `SpringTestManager` after the breakpoint - it refers to an object of some generated Spring class and shows me "Source not found".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have largely modified my question to make it better understandable. If more info is needed, I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

The lines in your stacktrace that does not have source, really *do not* have source.

They are generated from raw bytecode as manipulated by cglib - apparently in order to implement an AspectJ enhancement to your code.

This is one of the disadvantages of having libraries magically transforming your code behind your back.

Comment: Ok so I was able to move one step forward. It is able to find `Cglib2AopProxy` class once I attached the respective source jar file from spring website. Now its stuck on the next line, which is strange because the class `SpringTestService` is written by me and attached in source but still the debugger cant find the source for it.

Comment: No, the next line is "SpringTestService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2f23d34d.update" not SpringTestService.

Comment: I realized this is a dynamic class generated by hibernate after spending some time on the internet (and also looking at the answer by Jay). Currently I am using "step filters" in Eclipse to skip through these generated classes, but it is only a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SpringTestService implementing any interface? If not Spring will try to use cglib to create proxy and autowire. To do so your application require cglib (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib) dependency. Can you give that a try. Or if your service and dao are not implementing any interface then in general its a good idea to have interface even though you have only one implementation.

Comment: Yes I do not have an interface for my classes and it looks like Spring is doing the same as you wrote. For now I have a temporary solution - use step filters to filter out the unwanted (in terms of debugging) proxy classes. However If I have multiple apps, it will be really cumbersome filtering out each of the proxies generated for individual services. (I tried filtering out using patterns but it doesnt seem to work.)

Comment: Can you share your project? via bitbucket/github? Also which version of spring, tomcat you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I know its past long time, but this issue is caused by tomcat.
you will have to stop your tomcat server double click on it.
1. click on open launch configuration
2. goto classpath tab
3. click on add External Jars
4. Select commons-daemon.jar and tomcat-juli.jar from your tomcatdirectory\bin folder
5. run it in debug again and you won't see the error...

Comment: In my case, it turns out there were some proxy cassed being generated by Hibernate on the fly and I was unable to step into them. The only solution I found was to create a "step filter" in Eclipse to skip these classes.